# Is there permalink in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-2

As title says , I've tried to look for it and didn't find a way to do it.
Did I miss it or it wasn't implemented yet ?

I consider switching to OL 3 because of the export feature (I want to add easy print of application).

Answer (score 1):

There's no permalink control yet in OpenLayers.

https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/589

Feel free to contribute to the project if you feel that this feature is important. It can be by submitting code or by funding someone to do it for you ([Mapgears](http://mapgears.com/), [Boundless](http://boundlessgeo.com/), [CampToCamp](http://camptocamp.com/), [Terrestris](http://www.terrestris.de/), [etc](http://www.osgeo.org/search_profile)).